# How do Data Leak Prevention (DLP) implemented in Google or Facebook workspace?

Tags: dlp, insider-threats

I wonder how do Data leak prevention for mitigate insider threat being implemented in mature company/organization, ex. Google, Facebook, Netflix?

What tools that are used?
How do they have visibility and controls to their protected data? either in data creation, transmit, or access?